# Prove that the dual of the matrix norm $||x||_A = \sqrt{x^T A x}$ equals its inverse $||x||_A^* = ||x||_{A^{-1}}$

Tags: normed-spaces, duality-theorems

As per definition in an Introduction to Online Convex Optimization by E. Hazan (
2015). 
Can't figure out to proof that the dual norm of the following defined matrix norms equals the inverse matrix norm:

$||x||_A = \sqrt{x^T A x}$

$||x||_A^* = ||x||_{A^{-1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. (You need to assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite, which ensures that $x^T A x > 0$ for all nonzero $x$.)

We assume $x \neq 0$, otherwise the result is trivial.
First recall that
$$
\|x\|_{A}^\ast := \sup\{x^T y : y^T A y \leq 1\}
$$

So consider $y = A^{-1} x/\sqrt{x^T A^{-1} x}$ (the denominator is nonzero since $A$ is full rank and $x$ is nonzero).  Note that $y^T A y = 1$, and hence this implies $\|x\|_{A}^\ast \geq  \sqrt{x^T A^{-1} x}$.

Conversely, note whenever $y^T A y \leq 1$, we may define $z = A^{1/2} y$, in which case  $x^T y = x^T A^{-1/2} z$, where $\|z\|_2 \leq 1$. But then by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $x^T y \leq \|A^{-1/2} x\|_2 \|z\|_2 \leq \sqrt{x^T A^{-1} x}$. Passing to the supremum over $y$, we have shown $\|x\|_{A}^\ast \leq \sqrt{x ^T A^{-1} x}$.

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: @Drew Brady, are you sure that symmetric and invertible suffices? I think you need positive-definite matrix. Otherwise $x^TAx$ might be negative...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will update this above.